# Using 2 distinct mouse events in flex

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, gui-design

Am working on a  flex project

I am looking to provide some UI functionality using the mouse- I have two distinct UI events to be achieved via mouse
a) change value 
b) delete object

I don't seem to have sufficient mouseclick events for both. I am avoiding using the right click as it has some default options(whose signing off will affect the whole project- not just this). I have mouse click used for change value- how do I use the doubleclick as the single-click events seems to get invoked prior?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish.  When the user clicks something the click event will fire once.  You can have multiple event listeners if you wish, each one firing off a different handler, or you could perform your two actions in the same event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private var doubleClickOccurred:Boolean = false;
        private var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 1);

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            myLabel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkSingleOrDoubleClick);
            myLabel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, checkSingleOrDoubleClick);

            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, handleClick);
        }

        private function checkSingleOrDoubleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(event.target == myLabel && event.type == MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK)
            {
                // set the flag and let the timer complete event
                                    // take care of the click handling
                doubleClickOccurred = true;
                trace(" double clicked");

            }
            else if( event.type == MouseEvent.CLICK)
            {
                // start timer to wait till the double click event 
                                    // gets called
                timer.start();
                trace("Starting timer");
            }

        }

        private function handleClick(event:Event):void
        {

            if(doubleClickOccurred)
            {
                // handle double click event
                trace("Yes");
            }
            else
            {

                // handle single click
                trace("No");
            }
            // reset flag for capturing future events
            doubleClickOccurred = false;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>


<s:Label id="myLabel" text="Click Me" doubleClickEnabled="true" />
```

Output:
1) If a there is a single mouse click on the Label, the Single click login i.e trace("No")  is invoked

2) In case of double click on the Label, the trace("yes")  is invoked.

I hope this piece of code answers your question about handling single and double click on Flex components.

Comment: you can increase the Timer delay from 100 if the double click doesnt get detected within the specified delay.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say too much without knowing what you're editing, what the values are, etc.

A common idiom is to show an "X" icon, say, on the edge of a selected item,  with clicks only on that icon triggering delete.